# SQL query diversification

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

How can I diversify SQL query in a following manner:

IF condition_A then select * into a from x 
IF condition B then select * into b from x

It seems like trivial operation, but cannot find or figure out the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IF` condition

```
IF condition_A 
begin 
select * into a from x 
End
If condition_B
Begin 
Select * into b from x
End
```

If there can be only one condition satisfied out of two, then change the second `If` to `else` statement